# Why am I getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined" for my chrome.tabs api extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I'm getting this error as I attempt to use chrome.tabs.query()

It's my understanding that popup.js files, as well as background pages (but not content pages) are able to use the chrome.tabs api. With that in mind, I use the api in my popup.js file and it has worked as intended for about 2 years now.

I recently discovered that the chrome extension no longer works, and after inspecting it the error is from chrome.tabs.query(), specifically chrome.tabs is undefined and so the query property cannot be found.

What the extension did before it broke was take all open urls and titles and store them in a text file which is then downloaded upon pressing the button in the popup.

**The Problem**

I'm not sure what changed or what needs to be fixed to get the extension back in working order.

---

**Error**

[image: the error]

---

**Files**

---

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Raincheck</title>
    <!--jquery-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <form id="form">
        <input id="input" type="text"/>
        <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Raincheck"/>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
```

**popup.js**

*the error is on line 4
[image: the error source]

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

//get tab urls
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {

    //set date for unique download identifier
    var monthNames = [
    "01", "02", "03",
    "04", "05", "06", "07",
    "08", "09", "10",
    "11", "12"
    ];
    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDate();
    var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    var name = "raincheck-"+year+"-"+day+"-"+monthNames[monthIndex]+"-"+hour+"-"+minutes+"-"+seconds;
    //set chrome tabs api variables
    var text = "";
    var i = 0;
    //instantiate custom name & buttons
    var name_input = null;
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

    //get & store tab data
    while (i < tabs.length){
        if (i != tabs.length-1){
            text += tabs[i].title + ": " + "\r\n" + tabs[i].url + "\r\n\r\n";
        }
        else{
            text += tabs[i].title + ": " + "\r\n" + tabs[i].url;
        }
        i++;
    }

    //fix military time
    if (day<10){day = "0" + day};

    if (hour > 12){
    hour = hour - 12;
    }

    //set download to start after user input validation & button press
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        name_input = $("input").val();
        if(name_input != null && /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]*$/.test(name_input) != false && /\S/.test(name_input) != false){
            name = name_input;
        }

        download(name,text);
    });

});

//text file download function
function download(filename, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}

});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "Raincheck",
"version": "1.2",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "save the urls of open tabs in a text file",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "raincheck.png",
    "default_title": "Raincheck tab saver",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
"tabs"
],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: 1. Your code is correct and works for me 2. Make sure to never set a breakpoint before the first access to any chrome.* API otherwise you'll hit a known bug in Chrome 3. Relaxing the default CSP and loading external scripts into the privileged extension context is a terrible idea because any site may get hacked. You should include and load jquery.js in the extension package instead.

Comment: Thanks, but do you have an ideas on why it would work for others but not for me? I don't know what might be conflicting with it.

Comment: If the above guesses were misses, my only other guess would be you're opening popup.html directly from disk so it has a file:// URL, which makes it run as a normal web content where chrome API isn't available.

Comment: Actually I am getting the same error. So will this disappear when I will upload the code.